# How can I add my app to the Settings of the iphone/ipad?

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I make it possible to add my app in the Settings tab of the iPad?

Like in here: [image: Settings Ipad]

As you can see there are 3 rows there. But I want my app in there as well.
How can I do this?

Comment: Dead Link ! Please update image for Setting ipad.

Comment: The image wasn't available so I added another one instead. If you have a better image, you can upload it, but upload it on Imgur using the insert image button in the editor so that it doesn't disappear like the other one did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a settings bundle for your app to appear in the settings app.

Check this [Tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/5/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 7):

You need to [include a Settings bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) in your app.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Even without the link this answer (and Simon Lee's as well) would answer the question that the OP asked. *How* to do that is a somewhat different question, and really more information than would make sense for an answer on SO. So while both answers are short, they're both answers rather than links to answers, i.e. not link-only answers.